# PyLint optional has no attribute is bugged

Tags: python, mypy

```
    def has_champion_id(self) -> bool:
        return bool(self.team_player and self.team_player.championId)

    def update_card(self) -> None:
        if self.has_champion_id():
            champion_image = get_champion_image(self.team_player.championId)
            self.champion_icon.setPixmap(champion_image)
```

The following code is saying that `self.team_player.championId` has `Item "None" of "Optional[TeamPlayer]" has no attribute "championId"mypy(error)` as an error. But, shouldn't that if statement be catching this? The if statement is catching whether or not it is `Optional` or not. Very weird! What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The typechecker can’t automatically understand how logic affects type correctness in the general case. You might be able to use [user-defined type guards](https://peps.python.org/pep-0647/) for this in a way that satisfies you; if not, just manually tell the typechecker that you know what you’re doing with a cast. (Or, if you never wanted type checking, turn off the typechecker.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `self.team_player.championId is not None`, or a `# type: ignore`, booleaness is not considered a user defined type guard by mypy.